# Checking Integer field is NULL

Tags: null, integer

I am trying to validating if condition whether the integer value is NULL or 0. Here is my code. But It was showing programming error saying that the "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null". Please help or advise me for further step.

```
while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
/**
 * Splitting the content of tabbed separated line
 **/
String datavalue[] = line.split("\t");
long timestamp = Long.parseLong(datavalue[0]);
timestamp=timestamp % DAY_MODULO_IN_MS;
int  value     = Integer.parseInt(datavalue[1]);            
if (Integer.parseInt(datavalue[1]) == null) {
    throw new TemplateNullValueException("ERROR! Resolution is contain NULL value for " + timestamp);
}
else
{
    this.bufferedFileContentMap.put(timestamp, value);                  
}
```

}

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

if (Integer.parseInt(datavalue[1]) == null) {

here is the problem,
Firstly you are converting it into integer and checking so check with 0

Comment: How to achieve to validate integer with NULL? I can't check with 0 since the 0 is the valid number for business requirement.

Comment: can you tell me what data is getting in line variable

Comment: try to check with 0 or -1

Comment: I have to validate the 2nd column which is integers with NULL or Blank. This second field contains resolutions for the particular TimeStamp milliseconds (Field field)

Comment: Correct me if my understand is wrong, I will have to check the Second field (datavalue[1]) length is 0. Right?

Comment: can you do 1 thing print value before if statement so will get idea about what value you will get and then check with if condition

Comment: yes try it bt not length but value because you are converting it into integer

Comment: I will check now and get back here.

Comment: what value you will get when printing value integer variable

Comment: Here is my sample data, (tab de-limited file) 1421103601000 529
1421103602000 542
1421103603000 588
1421103604000 610
1421103605000 633
1421103606000 675
1421103607000 699
1421103608000 717
1421103609000 727
1421103610000 771

Comment: I am getting 529, 542, 588 etc.,

Comment: so its looks like integer values so check it
if (Integer.parseInt(datavalue[1]) <= 0 ) {

Comment: I can understand but 0 or negative values are valid numbers here for business requirement. The possible is to check only NULL or BLANK

Comment: so you can make it convert it into string and check that empty or not

Comment: Now no program error, if (String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(datavalue[1])) == null) {